# How to make a warn command and a warnings list discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm working in discord.py rewrite and want to make a command called `~warn <user> <reason>` that warns the user and `~warns <user>` that shows the amount of warns that the user has. I have looked for a tutorial on this but almost all of them were in discord.js, and the ones that were in discord.py were all in async. Can someone help me code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [JSON Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for it, I'll make the command,

```py
async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['warns'] = 0

async def add_warns(users, user, warns):
    users[f'{user.id}']['warns'] += 1

@client.command()
async def remove_warn(ctx, user: discord.Member, amount: int=None):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    amount = amount or 1

    await update_data(users, user)
    await add_warns(users, user, -amount)

    if users[f'{user.id}']['warns'] <= 0:
        with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
            del users[f'{user.id}']['warns']
            del users[f'{user.id}']
            f.write(json.dumps(users, indent=4))
        return

    else:

        with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        await ctx.send(f'Removed {amount} warn for {user}')
        return

@client.command()
async def warns(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    user = user or ctx.author
    try:
        with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        warns = users[f'{user.id}']['warns']

        await ctx.send(f'{user} has {warns} warnings')
    except:
        await ctx.send(f'{user} dont have any warnings.')
```

Comment: How to you suppose I make a warn <user> <reason> command?

Comment: @TheAgencyMGE I Suggest you use JSON (The code above is the example) Or Use the SQLite3 (Database) Module

Comment: Number 1: It turns out your remove_warn command is actually the warn command. That was hard to understand.
Number 2: The Warns actually save for the user in every server. For example, lets say i warn a member in Server 1. It will say "Warned {user}" But when I go to server 2 and type "~warns {user}" it will say "{user} has one warning" even if i've never warned the user in that server.

Comment: You can add a category on the code, for a example warns[f'{user.guild.id}'][f'{user.id}'] ['warns'] or something,